# Javascript and Json Issues. Can you get an image link through js and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So know how to get particular information from a json file and display it on html id's.
Like so:
Javascipt:

```
function showFollows(b){
 alert(b._total);}
  $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/OptimalBread/follows.json?callback=?", function(b){document.getElementById("follows").innerHTML += b._total;});
```

Html:

```
<div id="follows"></div>
```

So how would I do that exact same thing is the image link was also in a json file. In the example above it gets the text from the file but is there I way I can make the image display? Here is what I tried:
Javascript:

```
function showImage(d){
 alert(d.logo);}
 $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/OptimalBread.json?callback=?", function(d){document.getElementById("twitchLogo").innerHTML += d.logo;});
```

Html:

```
<div id="twitchLogo"></div>
```

But that only displays the image link not the image. How would I be able to but the image link into a img src? 
 Thanks for the help! Let me know if what I am asking is clear or not.

Comment: I knew that a div wasn't an image tag. I just didn't know how to start the js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("twitchLogo").innerHTML += d.logo;
```

You should write this:

```
document.getElementById("twitchLogo").innerHTML += '<img src="' + d.logo + '">';
```

Answer (score 4):

you can create a new `img` tag and set that as the inner html using jQuery like so:

```
function showImage(d)
{
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/OptimalBread.json?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(d) { 
        $("#twitchLogo").html($("<img>", { src: d.logo }));
    });
}
```

or if you want to maintain the contents of `twitchLogo`

```
$("#twitchLogo").append($("<img>", { src: d.logo }));
```